# SAS simple row count

Tags: count, sas

I have a large data set which has all states included, currently looking at NE. I am looking at each state individually and I want to count the number of rows that are included in each state. I am currently using:

```
record_num = _N_;
```

BUT This gives me the row count of the first row which NE is included. Example, row 49752 is the first record_num:

```
49752
49753
49754
49756
49757
49758
```

I want:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want this to be equal to 1 instead. I could do:

```
record_num=_N_;
num = record_num-49751;
```

But I don't want to alter this code every time I change the state which would change the record_num.

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/enumerate.htm
The SAS UCLA tutorials are very useful references in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS by-group processing is what you need to be using.

For example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by state;
  if first.state then counter=0;
  counter+1;
run;
```

What that does is when STATE changes, the last record before the change has a variable `LAST.STATE` set to 1 (otherwise has a 0), and the next record (The first for the new value of state) has the variable `FIRST.STATE` set to 1 (otherwise 0).

So we set counter to 0 each time a new state is encountered, and increment it (`var+1;` increments the variable and retains it across rows).

If you want to only have the actual count, as vasja notes in comments, then add `if last.state;` before the run (which will only give you one row per state, the last one).

Comment: I'd add `if last.state then output;` before `run;`

Answer (score 2):

Some more alternatives to @Joe's answer.  You can use `proc means` to calculate the number of rows for each state.  I've used the sashelp.zipcode dataset as an example.  The `nway` option tells it to summarize by all of the variables in the `class` statement.  The `n=` option on the output statement tells it just to calculate the number of observations for the class variables (you could also choose other aggregate functions such as mean, sum, etc.).

```
proc means data=sashelp.zipcode nway missing noprint;
  class statecode;
  output out=want(keep=statecode _freq_) n=;
quit;
```

There's also the SQL approach which is my personal favorite as it's a widely understood syntax that can be used in multiple programming languages:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select statecode,
         count(*) as num_records
  from sashelp.zipcode
  group by 1
  order by 1
  ;
quit;
```